# Is it possible to take two values of one class to another class and use it?

Tags: c++, class

I am a beginner. And, i tried this one.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Square
{
    int Number;

    public:
    Square(int a): Number(a) {}

    int getSquare()
    {
        return Number*Number;
    }
};

class SumNumber
{
    Square a;
    int FirNum;
    int SecNum;

    public:
    SumNumber(int Number, int x, int y): a(Number),FirNum(x), SecNum(y) {}

    int getSumNumber() //output-er
    {
        return FirNum + SecNum + a.getSquare();
    }
};

int main() {
    SumNumber a(2,3,4); //sums up squared number 2, and 3 and 4 
    cout << "Sum of Numbers\t" << a.getSumNumber() << endl; //=11
}
```

But, what if I wanted to have 2 values of class Square

```
Class Square
{
    int Number;
    int NextNumber;

    public:
    ...
};
```

and on the other class

```
class SumNumber    //creating class SumNumber
{

    Square a;
    int FirNum; //first number
    int SecNum; //second number

    public:
    ...
};
```

Question is:
Is it possible to take two values declared in Square class into SumNumber? If so, how?

Comment: Can you clarify 'take two values'?  Do you mean simply access the two private values in Square directly inside class SumNumber?  If so, checkout the 'friend' keyword, or just define accessor functions.

Comment: Ya, I mean, if we can take Number from Square and use in SumNumber, is it possible to take NextNumber at the same time?

Comment: You mean adding a constructor `Square(int a, int b): Number(a), NextNumber(b) {}` ? You can indeed call that in the initializer list of `SumNumber` with something like `SumNumber(int number, int number2 int x, int y) : a(number,number2){}`. If that's not what you mean, please be more precise

Comment: I don't understand your question but to take any value from `Square` (`a` member in your `SumNumber` class) you need to first init all them then you can access by using `.` operator, normally.

Comment: Well, note that you can't currently access either Number or NextNumber contained within the Square class.  You only know Number because you're creating a Square class from number within SumNumber.  Presumably you'd have to pass in NextNumber too.  You're trying to get around your own access restrictions, so you should probably clarify what you're declaring private and understand why you're doing so.  If you really want or need to access these numbers, consider making them public.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is having a **getter**. it is just a method that can return a the value of a private member, since your square class is returning the square of a number
you can change it as follows:

```
class Square
{
    int Number;
    int nextNumber;

    public:
    Square(int a, int b): Number(a), nextNumber(b) {}

    int getNumberSquared()
    {
        return Number*Number;
    }

    int getNextNumberSquared()
    {
        return nextNumber*nextNumber;
    }
};
```

and in your other class you can have this:

```
    class SumNumber
    {
        Square a;
        int FirNum;
        int SecNum;

        public:
        SumNumber(int Number, int nextNumber,int x, int y):
 a(Number, nextNumber),FirNum(x), SecNum(y) {}

        int getSumNumber() //output-er
        {
            return FirNum + SecNum + a.getNumberSquared() + a.getNextNumberSquared();
        }
    };
```